# SharePoint managed properties issue when search on separate farm to site collection

Tags: search, sharepoint

We’re having problems with managed properties in a new SharePoint 2013 web application.  The managed properties are being used to display metadata and for sorting, however the metadata isn't being displayed and we’re getting the following error whenever we try to sort

```
Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.
```

I have seen this error before when the managed property in question weren’t defined, or set to sortable/refinable.  However, I can clearly see that this is not the case from the search schema and there are not errors in the Crawl Log.

After digging into the logs, all I can find is

```
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries. Exception=SortList
```

The application is being deployed into an integrated development environment, on a shared app farm.  Also, we are using a separate farm for Search so the managed properties are created there.  The application/managed properties worked as expected on a developers slice, however search was located on the same farm as the application.

We have tried recreating the content source, numerous full crawls, verified the managed properties are set correctly but still getting the same problem.

Has anybody any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that this was a bug from December CU/SP1 to the April CU.  Basically, there was an issue with the schema that could prevent new properties from actually getting added successfully. The fix was first released in the May security update and is in the June CU as well. (If you are on the October 2013 or older CU, then the bug isn't present there.)

Getting the latest June Update, and running a full crawl has everything working as expected.